# Не понимаю в чем проблема SQLSTATE[HY093]: Invalid parameter number: number of bound variables does not match number of tokens

Tags: php, html, mysql, база-данных, phpmyadmin

код php

```
<?php
    try {
        $conn = new PDO("mysql:host=localhost;dbname=pr17", 'root', '');
    
        if (empty($_POST['main_name'])) exit("Поле не заполнено");
        if (empty($_POST['email'])) exit("Поле не заполнено");
        if (empty($_POST['note_name'])) exit("Поле не заполнено");
        if (empty($_POST['note_text'])) exit("Поле не заполнено");
        
        $query = "INSERT INTO pr17 (author_name, author_email, heading, body_text) VALUES (:main_name, :email, :note_name, :note_text)";
        $msg = $conn->prepare($query);
        $msg->execute(['main_name'=>$_POST['main_name']]);
        $msg->execute(['email'=>$_POST['email'], 'author_email' => $author_email]);
        $msg->execute(['note_name'=>$_POST['note_name'], 'heading' => $heading]);
        $msg->execute(['note_text'=>$_POST['note_text'], 'body_text' => $body_text]);
        echo "aboba<br>";
        /*$msg_id = $conn->lastInsertId();*/
       
        header("Location: pr17.html");
    }
    
    catch (PDOException $e)
    {
            echo "error <br>". $e->getMessage();
    }
    
?>
```

код html

```
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
    <meta charset="UTF-8">
    <meta http-equiv="X-UA-Compatible" content="IE=edge">
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href='pr17.css' rel="stylesheet">
    <title>pr17</title>
</head>
<body>
    <h1>Введіть свій текст замітки новин до бази даних</h1>
    <form method="post" action="pr17.php">
    Ім'я
    <p><input class = "input_text" type = "text" name = "main_name" size = "10"></p>
    Email
    <p><input class = "input_text" type = "text" name = "email" size = "30"></p>
    Назва замітки
    <p><input class = "input_text" type = "text" name = "note_name" size = "20"></p>
    Додаткова інформація
    <p><input class = "textarea" type = "text" name = "note_text"></p>
    <p><input class = "submit" type = "submit" value="Відправити новини!"></p>
    </form>  
</body>
</html>
```

[image]

Скрин базы данных с phpMyAdmin

Comment: Он Вам пишет, что число параметров объявленных в запросе не совпадает с количеством тех, что Вы передаёте. $msg->execute(['main_name'=>$_POST['main_name']]); <- тут же всего один параметр, а должно быть 4: :main_name, :email, :note_name, :note_text

Comment: чего вы вообще пытаетесь добиться этой кучей execute ?